# Telnet tinyproxy port hangs on aws instance when connecting from other aws instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-proxy

I have Tinyproxy running on an aws instance, configured to allow access from the IP of another aws instance. The configuration file contains mostly defaults, aside from the port and allow IP:

**.conf**

```
Port xxxx
Allow xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Both instances are part of the same security group. In the security group's inbound settings, I've attempted to allow access to `Port xxxx`  via the private IP, public IP, and security group ID. At the same time, in the Tinyproxy config, I've attempted to set the allow IP to both the private IP and public IP.

I've attempted all of these combinations, but none seem to work for me. The only setting that appears to work is to configure the security group to allow access to `Port xxxx` from anywhere `0.0.0.0`.

Custom TCP rules allowing access to `Port xxxx` from non-aws systems work fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Connect from A to B should work by allowing access using sg-xxxxxxxx as the setting in the security group, if you connect from A to B using the private IP of B and allow A's private IP in config.  Being in the same SG does not allow instances to see each other unless the SG allows access from its own sg-xxxxxxxx identifier, or from the private IP of the originating instance.  Are you sure you've tried that?

Comment: I double checked it again, and it looks like I fat-fingered A's private IP in the config. Allowing access to Port xxxx via sg-xxxxxxxx worked after I made the adjustment in the config by setting the value to the correct IP.